# How to put this code to work (DAO/CRUD operations)

Tags: python, html, flask, crud

Im trying to code the CRUD operations for the first time and im getting this message when testing the update:

Dao.get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'

Where am i doing wrong?

Page call:

```
@app.route("/veiculos/edit/<id>", methods=["GET"])
def edit_veiculo(id):
    veicdao = VeiculoDao()
    veiculo = veicdao.get_veiculo(id)
    return render_template("cadastro.html", action='update', veiculo=veiculo)
```

Update (I think the error is here):

```
@app.route("/veiculos/update", methods=["POST"])
def update_veiculo():
    veicdao = VeiculoDao
    
    id = request.form.get("id") 
    
    veiculo = veicdao.get_veiculo(id)
    
    veiculo.placa = request.form.get("placa")
    veiculo.modelo = request.form.get("modelo")
    veiculo.ano = request.form.get("ano")
    veiculo.deadpool = request.form.get("deadpool")

    veicdao.update(veiculo)
    
    return redirect(url_for("veiculos_cadastrados"))
```

Get in DAO:

```
    #get
    def get_veiculo(self, id):
        conn = Database.get_connection()
        response = conn.execute(f"""
            SELECT id, placa, modelo, ano, deadpool FROM veiculo WHERE id = {id}
        """)
        
        row = response.fetchone()
        
        veiculo = Veiculo(
            row[1],
            row[2],
            row[3],
            row[4],
            id = row[0]
        )
        conn.close()
        return veiculo
```

entities:

```
class Veiculo:
    def __init__(self, placa, modelo, ano, deadpool, id=None):
        self.placa = placa
        self. modelo = modelo
        self.ano = ano
        self.deadpool = deadpool
        self.id = id
```

Database:

```
CREATE TABLE veiculo(
    id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT not null,
    placa varchar(7) not null,
    modelo varchar(24) not null,
    ano int not null,
    deadpool varchar(8) not null
);
```

When i click "Atualizar" (which is update in my language) it should update the table in the row where the ID is, but it's not happening i read the code so many times and i didn't find the error.

html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}

<ul class="page-nav">
    <l1>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-success" href="{{url_for('veiculos_cadastrados')}}">Voltar</a>
    </l1>
</ul>

{% if veiculo %}
    <h1><u>Atualizar cadastro</u></h1>
{% else %}
    <h1><u>Cadastrar novo</u></h1>
{% endif %}

<form class="crud c2" action="/veiculos/{{action}}" method="POST">

    <input type="hidden" value="{{veiculo.id}}" name="id"> <!-- There is the ID-->

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="placa">placa</label>
        <input value="{{veiculo.placa}}" type="text" class="form-control" name="placa" id="placa" required autocomplete="off">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="modelo">modelo</label>
        <input value="{{veiculo.modelo}}" type="text" class="form-control" name="modelo" id="modelo" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ano">ano</label>
        <input value="{{veiculo.ano}}" type="text" class="form-control" name="ano" id="ano" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="deadpool">setor</label>
        <select id="deadpool" name="deadpool" class="form-control">
            <option selected>Selecione o setor...</option>
            <option>1.O</option>
            <option>2.O</option>
            <option>3.O</option>
            <option>4.G</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    {% if veiculo %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Atualizar</button>
    {% else %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Salvar</button>
    {% endif %}

</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

Update:
I just forgot to put "()":

```
veicdao = VeiculoDao
veicdao = VeiculoDao()
```

Comment: please update the question with edit option, not adding answers.